# Downloading file from web in Python with aspx file

Tags: python, asp.net, download

I found some python code on the web to download an attachment from a website (e.g. an excel or pdf file). This code works perfectly. Except when the weblink to download a file shows aspx or asph. The following code snippet works. However when I change the variable called url below with a link with aspx or ashx in it then it does not download.
E.g. if I replace by **url = 'https://kingcounty.gov/~/media/depts/health/communicable-diseases/documents/C19/data/vax_public.ashx?la=en'**

How do I fix this?

```
import requests
 
print('Download Starting...')
 
url = 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_tutorial.pdf'
 
r = requests.get(url)
 
filename = url.split('/')[-1] # this will take only -1 splitted part of the url
 
with open(filename,'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.content)
 
print('Download Completed!!!')
```

Comment: The code parsing the filename from the url will result in a filename of "vax_public.ashx?la=en" when you use the URL you indicate is problematic. That being said, I cannot reproduce your issue.  The code you posted does download a file.  I downloaded the file using `curl` and  the MD5 was the same for both files, and they were both identified as 'Microsoft OOXML' files.  (Note, I tested using python version 3.9.1)

Answer (score 1):

In your code `filename = url.split('/')[-1]`
is right for **`http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_tutorial.pdf`**

But `filename = url.split('/')[-1]` is not suitable for **`https://kingcounty.gov/~/media/depts/health/communicable-diseases/documents/C19/data/vax_public.ashx?la=en`**

So change the filename syntax. Take a filename in a string with a file extension like

`filename = 'filename.xlsx'`

```
import requests
print('Download Starting...')
url = 'https://kingcounty.gov/~/media/depts/health/communicable-diseases/documents/C19/data/vax_public.ashx?la=en'
r = requests.get(url)
filename = 'filename.xlsx'
with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.content)
print('Download Completed!!!')
```